# html5 webpages on multi display screen

Tags: html, gridview, display

how to code for website which will run on multi screen displays.
These displays are made by combining multiple led screens or monitors. 
Each monitor will either display a separate webpage or will one web page be divided into grids to display accordingly?

Comment: Just use grids and the computer hardware will do the thing.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, just build the page as normal and let the hardware do the patchworking.

Comment: so like a single webpage responsive enough to run on a very large scale screen and hardware should divide it in grids?

Comment: @prateekdesai - Exactly. The hardware will scale the page and handle sub division.